# _root.loadmove() in AS3?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript-2

What is the AS3 equalevent of the following AS2 code in AS3? I don't want to load the new swf into my main swf, I want it to compleatly replace it like this in AS2.

```
_root.loadMovie(swfURL);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to replace. Load your swf with `Loader` and attach it to your stage. You may remove all other `DisplayObjects` which are attached to stage, and you will be fine.

Comment: Will there be any problems with AS3 loading an AS2 swf?

Comment: see the docs for the actual example code for how to do this: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Loader.html#includeExamplesSummary (in this case, a SWF works the same as a GIF)

Comment: also, as it's an AS2 swf, it'll actually come in as a `AVM1Movie`, not a `MovieClip`: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/AVM1Movie.html

Comment: @Owen: The loader will return you an `AVM1Movie`. This will have some restrictions but it should run mostly normal. but that has nothing to do with your question.

Answer (score 1):

sample code for loading a swf...

```
var mySwfUrl:String="http://someurlhere.com/swf.swf";
var loadedSwf:MovieClip = null;// null until loaded
var loader:Loader=new Loader();
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,handlerSwfLoaded);
loader.load(new URLRequest(mySwfUrl));

function handlerSwfLoaded(event:Event):void{
    loader.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,handlerSwfLoaded);
    loadedSwf=event.target as MovieClip;
}
```

if you want to add the new swf to the display list

```
holder.addChild( yourSwfReference );
```

if you want to remove it

```
holder.removeChild( yourSwfReference );
```

if the swf is displayed somewhere currently... such as on holder... calling this will remove it from holder and add it to anotherHolder

```
anotherHolder.addChild( yourSwfReference );
```

Answer (score 1):

if you keep your swf files in your local machine then try this.

```
var loader:Loader = new Loader();
loader.load(new URLRequest("external.swf"));
addChild(loader);
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this may be 2 actual questions:

1. loading movies
2. loading a movie on the root stage

Answers

1. you can use a Loader and add it to either the object or its stage
2. add a static reference to the desired 'root' object and add the loader to the static reference.

If you need sample code let me know.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, could a see some sample code for loading a movie onto the root. Basically what I'm trying to do is have the movie completely replaced by the new loaded in one, if that's possible.

Answer (score 0):

In AS3 you cannot replace the loaded movie clip like in AS2.

The Loader class can load content in to be attached to the main stage.

You may want to create a wrapper class that loads in your initial content, and then switches that content out when making another load request.

Comment: And how would I deal with different framerates and dimensions?

Answer (score 0):

You can't replace in the manner you're trying
There's no way to replace a root level swf from said swf.

You could with javaScrit. A javaScript function can be called from AS3 and the JS function could replace the swf.

Or

To do this in AS3, you could make a main.swf that does nothing but load other content. Check out [the Gaia Framework for Flash](http://gaiaflashframework.tenderapp.com/home). It will handle loading and unloading of content for you. [totallynerdy.com](http://totallynerdy.com/) has many helpful tutorials for Gaia.